# Map through array of arrays, to find id and change object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of ids `['id1', 'id3']`.

I also have an array of `items`:

```
[
      {
        children: [{
                  children: [{
                            id: "id1", //This is value I need to find
                            status: { state: false}, //this is value I need to change
                            }],
                  }],
      },
      {
        children: [{
                  children: [{
                            id: "id2", 
                            status: { state: false}, 
                            }],
                  }],
      },
      {
        children: [{
                  children: [{
                            id: "id3", 
                            status: { state: false}, 
                            }],
                  }],
      },
    ]
```

My goal is to find every `item` by id from first array, and change attribute `state`, then return all `items` having included those I have changed.

This was my try, but it returns all items again, also Im not sure how to change the attribute.

```
items.filter(item =>
  item.children.map(child =>
     child.children.map(object =>
        idsArray.map(id => id === object.id)
)))
```

Comment: May be it will be helpful to update the question with some example data which can be used to execute the logic - as well as share your current logic (with _map function, containing more map functions inside_) to help community members refine/update that to make it work?

Comment: First of all, your data ins invalid ... both, the outer and the inner `children` are arrays, so their elements should either be array, objects or primitive types, but `[ children: [...]]` or `[ id: "id1" ...]` are neither. Second: Do you want to update the existing array or do you want to create a new array?

Comment: you Json file is invalid. try correcting it first. also if you can share the code which you wrote for above

Comment: *"but it returns all items again"*. So *what* do you want to be returned? Please post the expected result based on your data ...

Comment: Sorry for invalid data example in first version of question. Im new at this and hope next time I will be able to write my question right. Thank you for all your advices, for future.

Comment: The point of question was to update the existing array, and return it with updated items. Im sorry for not making it understandeble from first try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use recursive function something like below :

```js
let ids = ["id1", "id2"];
let arrayOfItems = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [
          {
            id: "id1",
            status: {
              state: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [
          {
            id: "id2",
            status: {
              state: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [
          {
            id: "id3",
            status: {
              state: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function changeStatus(arrayOfItems, ids) {
  return arrayOfItems.map((e) => {
    if (e.id && ids.includes(e.id)) {
      return { ...e, status: { state: true } };
    } else if (e.children) {
      return { ...e, children: changeStatus(e.children, ids) };
    } else {
      return { ...e };
    }
  });
}

console.log(changeStatus(arrayOfItems,ids));
```

Comment: As we currently neither know how the input data looks like (what OP has posted so far is just invalid) nor what the output should look like (OP hasn't said anything about that) this is mere speculation ...